# Convert .CSV to .XLSX with Text to Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to convert CSV to Excel, Using Text to Column Function.

I have tried using Text to column after the conversion but data is not relevant, So need to use Text to column function while converting the file from CSV to XLSX

```
Sub CSVtoXLSX_Conversion()

Dim ObjWorkbook As Workbook
Dim myfile As String
CSV_File_Source = "C:\Downloads\Input.csv"
EXCEL_File_Source = "C:\Downloads\Output.Xlsx"

Workbooks.OpenText Filename, OriginL=-535, StartRow:=1, Datatype:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsequtiveDelimeter:=False, Tab:=False, SemiColon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:=",", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1,1), Array(2,2)),TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

Set ObjWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not able to understand what you try doing and what problem you really have... Please, try explaining **in words** what you try accomplishing versus what is happening using the actual code. Does the csv file has only two columns? Do you want the first column to be formatted as general and the second one as text? If not, what do you need, from this point of view? Where do you use "Text to Column Function"? Do you understand what `TextToColumn` means in Excel? Then, your code uses `Comma:=False` but uses `Other:=True, OtherChar:=","`, which is the same...

Comment: @FaneDuru - I have been trying to convert an CSV file to XLSX, Where i have to use Text to column function as well while doing the conversion. I am not familier to it, Need help doing so, In the above script i have tried with 2 columns but it was not working.

Comment: You did not clarify my questions... You probably try **opening** the file with a desired format. Can you explain **which to be the format of each column**? Otherwise, nobody can help you, if not explaining what you need... Then, your code does not try any conversion. It only tries opening a csv file in Excel. We can show you how to save it as xlsx, but this can be done only **after we understand what you try doing in terms of EACH column formatting during opening**. At least, do you confirm that the file has only two columns? Maybe, it would be good to show us  how the file looks...